# Saving data from dropdown list Yii

Tags: yii, yii-chtml

I am trying to save values from dropdown list into my table column role.
**form**

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('role', $model, $model->getRoleOptions(),
                array('empty' => '---select role---'));
            ?>
```

**model**

```
public function getRoleOptions(){
    return array('1' => 'Administrator', '2' => 'Center Administrator');
}
```

The value is not being saved. I have also declared role as safe.

Comment: Have you check the [log](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging), it's located in protected\runtime\application.log? Have you put your dropdownlist inside the form?

Comment: Maybe you need to configure the log. See [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `activeDropDownList()` instead of `dropDownList()`. If you get a dump from your post request, you probably see invalid $_POST value with `dropDownList()`.

[activeDropDownList() method](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeDropDownList-detail)